# Python ZMQ REQ to REP not receiving message

Tags: python, pyzmq

I have an issue with my python ZMQ script, where all of a sudden, my REP client does not receive the message sent from the REQ server.

Server connection:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.50.11:5556")
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 12000)

socket.send_string("message", zmq.NOBLOCK)
body = socket.recv().decode("utf-8")
print(body)
```

Client connection:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:{}".format(5556))
while True:
    request = socket.recv().decode("utf-8")
    print(request)
```

The client never gets past the recv() function and hence it is not able to send a response and after a while the server will time out.

I don't have any tracebacks or anything that leads me to the cause of the issue.
It has worked for a long time, but all of a sudden it stopped working.

Any help is  greatly appreciated!

Best regards
Martin

Comment: It helps if the code you present in your question is runnable as-is; the use of `self.` in the first sample means that code won't run without modification. Additionally, there are syntax errors in the code (e.g., the unquoted string in the call to `connect`).

Comment: fixed the code to remove the self. and added the ip as a string and replaced message with string

Comment: Is the ip address `192.168.50.11` correct? Are there any firewall rules that might prevent that connection between the two pieces of code? If I take your code as written, but run both scripts on the same host and use `socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556")`, it all runs without a problem.

Comment: There are a number of ways you could diagnose this problem: something like [`strace`](https://strace.io/) would let you trace system calls in the `REQ` code to see if it's successfully establishing a connection. Using [netcat](https://nmap.org/ncat/), you could set up a listener in place of your `REP` code and verify that the `REQ` code is connecting.

Comment: The IP is correct yes, but unless windows has blocked the address by it self in the last month, it should not be blocked

Comment: . . . It was a mix of windows and myself that was the issue. A while ago my net dropped out, so I used the network troubleshooting tool. It suggested resetting my network adapters and with it the ip configuration. If you are still here larsks, you can write anything as a solution and I will accept it. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out!